# Android correct place to inflate custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have this custom view:

```
class BaseView extends FrameLayout() {
     @Override
     void onAttachedToWindow() {
         View.inflate(context, R.layout.view, this)
     }
}
```

The correct place to inflate my custom view is in the onAttachedToWindow method?

I am thinking that maybe inflating it after the onAttach can make the parent layout to be entire redraw.

If it is wrong to inflate in the onAttachedToWindow, where is the right place?

This view is added dynamically (via addView) and in others places it is placed in the xml definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place to inflate your custom view layout is in the constructor:

```
class BaseView extends FrameLayout {
    public BaseView(Context context) { this(context, null); }

    public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, this, true);

        ...
    }
}
```